# Para que serve ~ (til) e ^ (acento circunflexo) no esquema de versionamento do Composer?

Tags: composer

Em alguns casos, vejo que algumas bibliotecas que usam o [Composer](https://getcomposer.org), colocam `~` ou `^` no início da versão da biblioteca, assim:

```
"orchestra/testbench" : "^3.6"
```

Ou

```
"phpunit/phpunit"    : "~7.0"
```

Eu queria saber qual é a finalidade de cada um deles.

Comment: A quem interessar, segue a [documentação](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#next-significant-release-operators), só peço, por gentileza, não apenas copiar e colar como resposta.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss você pegou o espírito da coisa. Procurei algum conteúdo sobre isso na internet, em português, e não achei nada muito interessante.

Comment: Se não me engano e igual ao do cocoapods, seja lá qual for

Comment: Só pra comentar, alguns devs não seguem o semver.org, ai vem aquilo, da versão 1.0.1 para 1.0.2 tem algo que muda bruscamente o comportamento, ai vai e falha tudo no teu projeto, tenho tanto receio que só uso "x.x.x", sem range :P

Comment: Eu sei que o [NPM](https://github.com/npm/node-semver) usa a mesma notação. Só não sei se seria pertinente adicinar isso à reposta.

Comment: Realmente, existem subtilidades entre NPM e Composer. [Deviation from npm/semver in tilde range constraint](https://github.com/composer/semver/issues/14).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Resumo

Considere o modelo de [versionamento semântico](https://semver.org/lang/pt-BR/): MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH

O **operador til (~)** permite que último digito seja incrementado

```
~MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH  >=MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH e < MAJOR.(MINOR+1).0
```

Ou seja, todos os PATCHs da versão MAJOR.MINOR

exemplo: ~ 1.2.3 irá corresponder a todas os PATCHs lançados depois da versão 1.2.3. >1.2.3 e <=1.3.0

Outros exemplos:

```
"vendor/package": "~1.3.2", // >=1.3.2 <1.4.0
"vendor/package": "~1.3", // >=1.3.0 <2.0.0
```

O **operador circunflexo (^)**  procura a versão maior (MAJOR) mais recente.

Há uma exceção se a versão maior é zero. Neste caso o comportamento é buscar até a versão menor mais recente. Essa exceção existe para respeitar a [regra 4](https://semver.org/lang/pt-BR/#spec-item-4) do versionamento semântico:

> No início do desenvolvimento, a versão Maior DEVE ser zero (0.y.z). Qualquer coisa pode mudar a qualquer momento. A API pública não deve ser considerada estável."

exemplo: ^ 1.2.3 corresponderá a qualquer versão 1.x.x, incluindo 1.3.0, mas suspenderá no 2.0.0.

Outros exemplos

```
"vendor/package": "^1.3.2", // >=1.3.2 <2.0.0
"vendor/package": "^0.3.2", // >=0.3.2 <0.4.0 // exceção se a versão maior (MAJOR) é 0
```

### Explicando os exemplos da questão:

"orchestra/testbench" : "^3.6" - indica que pacote tem uma dependência com esta biblioteca e garante a compatibilidade com todas a versões igual ou superiores à versão 3.6, mas menores que a versão 4.minor

"phpunit/phpunit"    : "~7.0" - indica que pacote tem uma dependência no mínimo igual a 7.0, mas permite todos os 7.minor.patch

### Documentação

Segundo a documentação do [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md):

> ## Tilde Version Range (~)
>
> The ~ operator is best explained by example: ~1.2 is equivalent to >=1.2 <2.0.0, while ~1.2.3 is equivalent to >=1.2.3 <1.3.0. As you can see it is mostly useful for projects respecting semantic versioning. A common usage would be to mark the minimum minor version you depend on, like ~1.2 (which allows anything up to, but not including, 2.0). Since in theory there should be no backwards compatibility breaks until 2.0, that works well. Another way of looking at it is that using ~ specifies a minimum version, but allows the last digit specified to go up.
>
> ## Caret Version Range (^)
>
> The ^ operator behaves very similarly but it sticks closer to semantic versioning, and will always allow non-breaking updates. For example ^1.2.3 is equivalent to >=1.2.3 <2.0.0 as none of the releases until 2.0 should break backwards compatibility. For pre-1.0 versions it also acts with safety in mind and treats ^0.3 as >=0.3.0 <0.4.0.
>
> This is the recommended operator for maximum interoperability when writing library code.

Traduzindo:

## Faixa de Versão com operador Til (~)

O operador ~ é melhor explicado pelo exemplo: ~ 1.2 é equivalente a> = 1.2 <2.0.0, enquanto que ~ 1.2.3 é equivalente a> = 1.2.3 <1.3.0. Como você pode ver, é mais útil para projetos que respeitam versões semânticas. Um uso comum seria marcar a versão secundária mínima da qual você depende, como ~ 1.2 (que permite qualquer coisa até, mas não incluindo, 2.0). Como, em teoria, não deve haver intervalos de compatibilidade com versões anteriores até o 2.0, isso funciona bem. Outra maneira de ver isso é que usar ~ especifica uma versão mínima, mas permite que o último dígito especificado suba.

## Faixa de Versão com operador Circunflexo(^)

O operador ^ se comporta de maneira muito semelhante (ao operador ~), mas fica mais próximo de versões semânticas e sempre permitirá atualizações sem interrupções. Por exemplo, ^ 1.2.3 é equivalente a> = 1.2.3 <2.0.0, já que nenhum dos lançamentos até o 2.0 deve quebrar a compatibilidade com versões anteriores. Para as versões pré-1.0, ele também atua com a visando a segurança e trata ^ 0.3 como> = 0.3.0 <0.4.0.

Este é o operador recomendado para máxima interoperabilidade ao escrever o código da biblioteca.